# Decoding json in twitter using Eliiot Twitter For Codeigniter

Tags: api, codeigniter, twitter

Currently I`m trying to use elliot`s twitter library for CI at http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/ after installation, it went well. the source code worked well..

Then I try to add code at index() function which is like this :

```
function index()
        {
            echo 'hi there';

            $user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');

            $dec = json_decode($user);
        }
```

I tried to decode json by using json_decode() function but it return error

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

This is my first time working with json..
Is there something I missed out ?
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn`t need any variable convertion.
just access object directly like $dec->username

Answer (score 0):

You should juggling that object into string type...

```
 $user = (string) $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');
 $dec = json_decode($user);
```

Comment: It give me error  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Did you dump that var, whats that contain?